# How do I configure RestAssured http client to use socks proxy?

Tags: rest-assured, socks

Apparently [rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) misses support for socks proxies: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/934. Is there way to overcome this and despite all connect through proxy?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to provide own http client configuration:

```java
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig;
import io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.conn.DnsResolver;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpInetSocketAddress;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.Socket;

class SocksProxyTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldConnectUsingProxy() {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 2000));
        String statusLine = RestAssured.given()
            .config(
                RestAssuredConfig.config()
                    .httpClient(
                        HttpClientConfig.httpClientConfig()
                            .httpClientFactory(() -> getSocksProxyConfiguredHttpClient(proxy)))
            )
            .get("http://example.com")
            .getStatusLine();
        System.err.println(statusLine);
    }

    private DefaultHttpClient getSocksProxyConfiguredHttpClient(Proxy proxy) {
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", 80, new ProxiedPlainSocketFactory(proxy)));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 443, new ProxiedSSLSocketFactory(proxy, SSLContexts.createSystemDefault())));
        DnsResolver fakeDnsResolver = host -> new InetAddress[] { InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1 }) };
        PoolingClientConnectionManager ccm = new PoolingClientConnectionManager(schemeRegistry, fakeDnsResolver);
        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm);
    }

    static class ProxiedPlainSocketFactory extends PlainSocketFactory {

        private final Proxy proxy;

        public ProxiedPlainSocketFactory(Proxy proxy) {
            this.proxy = proxy;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(HttpParams params) {
            return new Socket(proxy);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() {
            return new Socket(proxy);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket connectSocket(Socket socket, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress, InetSocketAddress localAddress,
                                    HttpParams params) throws IOException, ConnectTimeoutException {
            InetSocketAddress unresolvedRemote = InetSocketAddress
                .createUnresolved(((HttpInetSocketAddress) remoteAddress).getHttpHost().getHostName(), remoteAddress.getPort());
            return super.connectSocket(socket, unresolvedRemote, localAddress, params);
        }
    }

    static class ProxiedSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

        final Proxy proxy;

        public ProxiedSSLSocketFactory(Proxy proxy, SSLContext sslContext) {
            super(sslContext, ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            this.proxy = proxy;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(HttpContext context) throws IOException {
            return new Socket(proxy);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket connectSocket(int connectTimeout, Socket socket, HttpHost host, InetSocketAddress remoteAddress,
                                    InetSocketAddress localAddress, HttpContext context) throws IOException {
            InetSocketAddress unresolvedRemote = InetSocketAddress
                .createUnresolved(((HttpInetSocketAddress) remoteAddress).getHttpHost().getHostName(), remoteAddress.getPort());
            return super.connectSocket(connectTimeout, socket, host, unresolvedRemote, localAddress, context);
        }
    }

}
```